# In error correcting, "Most of the magnesium used in the US comes from the seawater."

Tags: articles, redundancy

> Most of the magnesium used in the US comes from **the** seawater.

I said there's no error in here. But the teacher says "the" (from the seawater) is redundant. But I think it's necessary cause the US don't take from all the seas in the world but only the specific seas accordingly. So we are specifying some specific seas. Not in general like seawater is salty and like that. So is there any error in the sentence? Is "the"( from the seawater) redundant or necessary?

Answer (score 2):

In general, mass nouns like "seawater" tend not to get definite articles until they have been separated into a discrete unit.

An analogue would be:

> I like to drink milk with my breakfast.

As opposed to (the incorrect version):

> I like to drink the milk with my breakfast.

To compare to your original question, even if you know that you usually go to the same store for milk each time you buy it, "the" is redundant, as that is assumed to be incidental to the identity of the milk.  You could get milk from a different store, and it would not change your breakfast.

In the same sense, your original sentence tells me that the specific collection point of the seawater in question is irrelevant to the extraction of magnesium.  It implies that seawater inherently contains dissolved magnesium, and that the process would be unchanged by selecting a different source of seawater.  As far as the grammar is concerned, the fact that the US does not take water from all of the seas of the world is an accident of geography.

Answer (score 0):

"the" is not redundant, it's just wrong. There's a difference between a specif*ic* thing thing and a specif*ied* thing. For instance, if I say "I ate an apple", even though there was a specific apple that I apple, I didn't say what it was, so the indefinite article is appropriate. If I say "I ate the apple that was on the counter", now I've said which apple I ate, so the definite article is appropriate. Even if the US is using specific seawater, we aren't told what seawater is used, so a definite article is not appropriate.